# Переход к предыдущим фрагментам по нажатию на кнопку "Back"

Tags: android, android-fragment

У меня имеется контейнер,в который подгружаются фрагменты. Изначально в контейнер подгружается NavigationFragment - панель с кнопками (категориями),при нажатии на какую -либо из них происходит  переход либо к подкатегориям ,либо к контенту(ChildItemFragment), который содержит категория.
Мне нужно реализовать логику возврата к предыдущей подкатегории при нажатии на программную кнопку "Back" или же к навигационной панели,если категория не имеет подкатегорий.

я пробовал такие варианты :

```
FragmentManager manager = MainActivity.this.getFragmentManager();
    int count = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
if (count > 0) manager.popBackStack()
else  .... transaction.replace .....commit  NavigationFragment
```

но этот подход не работает (при начале транзакции прописывал .addToBackStack(null) )

еще пробовал при создании моего ChildItemFragment передавать из него в MainActivity список с элементами

```
 list.remove(list.size() - 2);
ChildListFragment fragment = new ChildListFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putParcelableArrayList(ChildListFragment.ARG_CHILD_ITEMS, childs);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right)
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

но в этом случае получается какой-то непонятный костыль,который работает с переменным успехом и иногда бывают вылеты в зависимости от количества подкатегорий. 
подскажите,как правильно реализовать возврат к предыдущим экранам в контейнере при нажатии на  программную Back button

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то у вас есть фрагменты в активити, а так же в некоторых из них есть дочерние фрагменты добавляющиеся через getChildFragmentManager() родительского фрагмента. По скольку что вы подразумеваете под "этот подход не работает" вы не уточнили, предположу что у вас откатываются изменения только фрагментов размещенных в активити. Происходит это от того что вы в обработчике кнопки назад проверяете только бэкстек FragmentManager'а активити (`getBackStackEntryCount()` и `popBackStack()`), соответственно вам просто нужно проверять и бэкстек дочерних FragmentManager'ов фрагментов.